# Block download of YouTube videos

Tags: youtube

Is it possible to block somebody from downloading a YouTube video? I don't want people stealing my videos.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible with YouTube, but you can try the following:

- watermark your videos (don't overdo it)
- make the video private and share the link only to people you trust
- try another video sharing service that encrypts the streams so
     they can't be easily captured/downloaded

Comment: There are tools to record whatever is playing on your screen. So even if the stream is encrypted, it can be re-recorded with a lower quality though it can't be downloaded